# Excluding properties on domain model objects from JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON to serialize a graph of objects which are defined in a satellite assembly. I have a circular reference which is causing the recursion limit in JSON to be exceeded and adding extra bloat to an already data heavy POST.

The documented way would be to add a `JsonIgnore` attribute to the property on my data object, but that would require a Newtonsoft.Json reference in my domain project. Is there any other way of excluding a property from serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute on the model properties, which references `System.Runtime.Serialization`. All other properties will be serialized by default.

e.g.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SerializedProperty { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string IgnoredProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem with minimal effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative 1**

You should be able to use `[DataContract]` together with `[DataMember]`.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDomainModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PublicString { get; set; }

    public string HiddenString { get; set; }

    public MyDomainModel InfiniteReference { get; set; }
}
```

It requires a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization`.

Example:

```
[HttpGet]
public MyDomainModel GetModels()
{
        var model = new MyDomainModel
        {
            HiddenString = "Hidden",
            PublicString = "Public",
        };
        model.InfiniteReference = model;
        return model;
 }
```

Output:

```
{
"publicString": "Public"
}
```

---

**Alternative 2**

> I have a circular reference [...]

You could use [`ReferenceLoopHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_referenceloophandling.htm), which simply cuts the circular reference. But this might not be want you want, when you mentioned other *extra bloat*.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. I solved it in an entirely overwrought and overengineered fashion with a custom attribute and contract-resolver, when serializing, so I didn't need to reference any external libs (with the exception of System) in my model.

Declare your own attribute, such as

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class IgnoreMeAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Decorate your model

```
[IgnoreMe]
public string IgnoreMePlease { get; set; }
```

Add a

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public static readonly ShouldSerializeContractResolver Instance = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof (IgnoreMeAttribute), false).Any())
            property.ShouldSerialize = instance => false;

        return property;
    }
}
```

and use it

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = ShouldSerializeContractResolver.Instance });
```